# Why isn't the Line Feed (&#10;) character rendering properly in the Google Chrome browser via XSLT on the Client?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome, xslt

**Background:**

I've created a simple web page, based around a Book Store, which is populated by a combination of XML and *XSLT (1.0)* documents using the [on the client via Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp) method.

One of my XML elements, (`<synopsis></synopsis>`) contains a large amount of text, which I've manually separated into paragraphs with line/return breaks. However, when outputting this node via XSLT, I found these line breaks were ignored and the node was instead delivered in one big block of uninterrupted text.

I wanted to be able to output each of these manual text blocks as HTML paragraphs, surrounded by `<p></p>` tags, so, utilising a useful XSLT template, which uses the line-feed character (`&#10;`) as the delimiter and applies normalizing to the remaining white-spaces, I have now managed to pass this node in the way I intended... *Well nearly*.

**The Problem:**

In the Internet Explorer and Firefox browsers this XSLT template works perfectly and the paragraphs are formed and outputted without any issues.

**IE:**

[image: IE Screenshot]

**Firefox:**

[image: Firefox Screenshot]

But in the **Google Chrome** browser, I'm assuming that the `&#10;` (line-feed) character is processed or interpreted in a different way when specifically using the *XSLT on the Client* method/setup? I say this because instead of paragraphs being formed after every line-feed character, they are in fact created after every single word!

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

Bizarrely, this is in direct contrast to when I've used a basic XML/XSLT connection structure (without the JavaScript/On the Client method), where the paragraphs are outputted properly in every available browser, including Google Chrome! *Strange*.

**The Setup:**

Here is my HTML/JS/XML/XSLT setup, so people can recreate my exact problem.

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Book Store</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="books.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="content">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function loadXMLDoc(filename) {
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
else 
  {
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult(xml,xsl)
{
xml = loadXMLDoc("books.xml");
xsl = loadXMLDoc("books.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
  {
  ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = ex;
  }
// code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
  document.getElementById("content").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}

window.onload=function() {

  displayResult('books.xml','books.xsl');
}
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <title>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>1997</year>
    <price>3.99</price>
    <publisher>Bloomsbury (UK)</publisher>
    <synopsis>
         Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone is the first novel in the Harry Potter series and J. K. Rowling's debut novel.

         The plot follows Harry Potter, a young wizard who discovers his magical heritage as he makes close friends and a few enemies in his first year at the Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry.

         With the help of his friends, Harry faces an attempted comeback by the dark wizard Lord Voldemort, who killed Harry's parents, but failed to kill Harry when he was just a year old.
   </synopsis>
 </book>
 <book>
    <title>The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo</title>
    <author>Stieg Larsson</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>5.99</price>
    <publisher>Norstedts Förlag (SWE)</publisher>
    <synopsis>
         In Stockholm, Sweden, journalist Mikael Blomkvist, co-owner of Millennium magazine, has lost a libel case brought against him by businessman Hans-Erik Wennerström. Lisbeth Salander, a brilliant but troubled investigator and hacker, compiles an extensive background check on Blomkvist for business magnate Henrik Vanger, who has a special task for him. 

         In exchange for the promise of damning information about Wennerström, Blomkvist agrees to investigate the disappearance and assumed murder of Henrik's grandniece, Harriet, 40 years ago. 

         After moving to the Vanger family's compound, Blomkvist uncovers a notebook containing a list of names and numbers that no one has been able to decipher.
    </synopsis>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My Bookstore</h2>
  <xsl:apply-templates/> 

  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
  <p>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="author"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="price"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="synopsis"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
  Book Title: <span style="color:#000000">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
  <br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="author">
  Author: <span style="color:#000000">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
  <br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="price">
  Price: <span style="color:#000000">
  &#163;<xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
  <br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="synopsis">
    Synopsis: <span style="color:#38A930">
    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </span>
    <br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'&#10;'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="normalize-space(substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter))" />
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <p>
                <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
            </p>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

**The Question:**

Therefore, does anybody know of a solution to tackle this very niche browser related problem? Can Google Chrome use any further hex codes to deal with line-feed breaks I could try? Can I possibly output paragraphs in the same way as I've done in Firefox and IE within Chrome when using the *On the Client* method of setting up my XSLT templates?

Any help or advice on this would be very warmly received. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: *"a large amount of text, which I've manually separated into paragraphs with line/return breaks"* - And that is your mistake right there. If "a paragraph" is a thing for your use case, then separate paragraphs into their own elements. That is what XML is about, after all.

Comment: Can you post any valid HTML 4 or HTML5 you want to create? Nested `p` elements are not valid, neither are `p` elements inside of `span` elements. So it is any parser's or implementations guess which rendering you want. And your XSLT creates a complete HTML document structure while your Javascript puts the transformation result into a `div` element, that is not going to result in a valid and well-defined document structure either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set up the parameter's default value using `<xsl:param name="delimiter" xml:space="preserve">&#10;</xsl:param>` then I think Chrome will do what you want, at least it does for me in a test case at http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2015102604.html. There seems to be a bug in Chrome when handling the character reference in an attribute value.